# Web App Builder and browser caching

Tags: arcgis-web-appbuilder, cache, html5, iis

At the request of my superiors, I'm having to make 1, sometimes multiple changes, to Web App Builder Developer sites throughout the day that include (searches, pop-ups, custom widgets, etc).  Upon reloading the new site files to IIS, users sometimes still see the previous settings in the sites.  I have to get them to actually clear their browser cache in order to see the new changes.  Is there any way around this??  I'm hoping there is some setting in IIS that may help with this..

Comment: With that many changes, I think that is normal but I am curious of the responses you'll get. If users clear their cache and opt instead for Incognito/Private browser mode it's usually much less of an issue. Once the changes stop (or become minimal) users could probably resume using normal browser mode. There are a lot of pluses for caching but here is a small bit I found about IIS caching that you might read through. https://www.ryanmcdonough.co.uk/2013/06/clear-client-browser-cache-with-iis/

Comment: @MapHound- Thanks for that link.  I will make that change in IIS that you brought to my attention and see if it helps.  I'm willing to try anything at this point because management thinks I don't  know what I'm doing and that clearing the cache is too hard.  I tried explaining in a nice way that you shouldn't make these kinds of changes during business hours.  crickets..

Comment: You got it. Hope it works! I can certainly understand that. If they are using Chrome, a quick clear cache is to press F12, then right click the refresh arrow and select "Empty Cache and Hard Reload."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on what @MapHound mentioned, without a sophisticated server-side logic, the most heavy-handed approach would be to set IIS to send headers to the browser indicating that content expires immediately, thus the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript files will never be cached by the browsers. This will obviously cause your site to feel like it loads slower since the browser will never cache anything, but it seems like based on your question that you're interested in this approach.

Simply to go the `IIS Manager` > `HTTP Response Headers` Area, `Set Common HTTP Response Headers` > `Expire Web Content: Immediately`. See [full instructions here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache).