# Web App Builder: updates not appearing in browser when we republish

Tags: arcgis-web-appbuilder, arcgis-portal, cache, iis

I have a Web App Builder (not Developer Edition) application that is hosted on IIS on a local server. I recently republished the app, but when I load the URL in a browser that has already loaded the app in the past, I'm seeing old un-updated content. Since it only seems to be an issue with browsers that have previously loaded the page, my assumption has been that this is related to browser caching somehow?

Based on other answers on this site [I've set custom headers to expire the cache immediately](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/283088/web-app-builder-and-browser-caching). I see a web.config file with the caching rules appear in my app directory. This results in prompting for the Portal credentials on page visit, but still displays the same stale app content.

Is there anything else I can try? I'm at a loss and a lot of the documentation seems to be specific to using the Developer Edition. I can shift to this if needed, but am looking for a solution with my current setup if possible.

Deployment info:

- ArcGIS Enterprise 10.9
- IIS v10.0
- No proxy set (mostly because I haven't seen the need for it)
- App published by configuring in WAB for Portal, downloading and unzipping onto my web app and adding to IIS as an application [following this advice](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-web-appbuilder-questions/arcgis-web-app-builder-iis/m-p/19030/highlight/true#M475).

Asking our user group to clear their browser caches is not a workable solution unfortunately.

Comment: Open the app in an incognito window of your browser. Does it work? If so it's definitely a cache issue. I have seen this many times before and clearing cache was always the solution.

Comment: @Tigerwoulds opening in an incognito browser does work, as does clearing the cache in another browser that had loaded the old application. The issue it that I need a solution that I can control from the development side as we can't, for various reasons, ask our users to clear their browser history/cache every time we push an update.